# Save plot from command line with no access to graphics

Tags: matplotlib, command-line-interface

I am attempting to save out a plot from a python script that is being run on a remote linux box with no access to GUI, and plt.plot() followed by plt.savrefig() esults in a graphics failure... is there a way to save out a plot from the command line without displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

First I would atempt to save the graphic as an array to disk and then download it via SSL:

```
canvas.draw()       # draw the canvas, cache the renderer

image = np.fromstring(canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8')

np.save('filename.npy', image)
```

alternatively you can try PIL, but I am not sure about your graphics issue:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.fromarray(image).save("filename.png")
```

Comment: I forgot to describe my data type... I have an array of numbers x = [1,2,3,4,5,6] that I would like to save out as a plot...

Comment: Then send the array to somewhere else and plot it there

Comment: not sure what you mean by that... its the plot function that is causing the script to fail because I don't have X tunneling set up

Comment: Well you can access the machine somehow or at least send/get code to the machine. Then just get the array in byte array or something else

Comment: so no way to simply suppress the plot gui?

Comment: I dont think that is your only problem since plt.savefig() is not working either. I can be that you are missing drivers rendering your image in the background or other issues with your system setup. There is no way to tell without further details